# Display file download field using the attached nodeid from a webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-webform

I have managed to get the node id from a Webform submission into views.
I have managed to get the nodeID and the attached file download pdf link field in to the same view.[image]

What I need is the last step so that when a customer looks at an article page, they fill in the webform and, upon submission, are taken to the 'views' page which displays only the pdf white paper link for the corresponding webform node.

[image: thenter image description here]

In other words I need to display the file download link with the corresponding Webform attached article node ID. Doing my head in.

Comment: All I am after is something like this site: http://www.datasitedeal.com/073113-MA-UK?CampaignID=701C0000000hzNg&LeadSource=Internet_Search[/link]. but using views, so the customer can upload the articles.